# Setting UIbutton image from a function from another class

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

So I have a list of songs, and when I click on the moreButton the SongDetailCell is presented and the `setPlayPauseOnAppeaering()` function is called on the selected song.

This function will either set a play or pause icon depending on the if statement. For some reason the pause-icon is not being, even though the correct console logs are being printed. For example, when **"playing with spotify sample"**, the button is not being set to pause, even though it definitely should be. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here.

```
class SongList: UICollectionViewCell    {

    @objc func moreButtonTap(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer)  {

        var indexPath = getIndexPathFromRecognizer(gesture: gesture)

        let songDetailView = SongDetailCell()
        let song = self.songsArray[indexPath.item]
        songDetailView.song = song
        songDetailView.setPlayPauseOnAppearing()
    }
}

class SongDetailCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    var song: Song! 

    let playPauseButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.setImage(UIImage(named: "play-button-large"), for: .normal)
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.tintColor = UIColor.brandBlack()
        button.contentMode = .scaleToFill
        return button
    }()

func setPlayPauseOnAppearing()    {

    func setPlayButton()  {
        playPauseButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "play-button-large")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate), for: .normal)
    }
    func setPauseButton()    {
        playPauseButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "pause-button-large")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate), for: .normal)
    }

    if SongPlayer.shared.doesPreviewExist(spotifyPreviewUrl: spotifyURL, iTunesPreviewUrl: itunesURL)   {
        if SongPlayer.shared.player.timeControlStatus == .paused    {
            if SongPlayer.shared.previewUrl == spotifyURL {
                setPlayButton()
                print("paused with Spotify sample")
            } else if SongPlayer.shared.previewUrl == itunesURL {
                setPlayButton()
                print("paused with iTunes sample")
            }
        }   else if SongPlayer.shared.player.timeControlStatus == .playing {
            if SongPlayer.shared.previewUrl == spotifyURL {
                setPauseButton()
                print("playing with Spotify sample")
            } else if SongPlayer.shared.previewUrl == itunesURL {
                setPauseButton()
                print("playing with iTunes sample")
            }
        }   else    {
                print("no audio sample")
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Probably the `withRenderingMode` gives you `nil` result.  Have you tried removing it?

Answer (score 0):

You are *creating* a button (`playPauseButton`). But none of your code ever actually puts that button into the interface. Thus you never see it. You are changing the icon just fine, but the button is off in memory somewhere.

The cell is parallel. You are saying

```
let songDetailView = SongDetailCell()
```

But that just makes a new cell, off in space somewhere. It is not the cell that actually is present in the interface. So what you do to it has no visible effect (and then it just vanishes in a puff of smoke).